# image_pipeline svn no longer exists on server

Tags: ros, image-pipeline, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to svn checkout image_pipeline using the link the ros wiki suggests, but the server is not responding.  I am using electric and need a svn source for image_pipeline. Can anyone tell me why image_pipeline is no longer on the svn server?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54066/image_pipeline-svn-no-longer-exists-on-server/) by [ee.cornwell](https://answers.ros.org/users/4115/ee.cornwell/) on ROS Answers with karma: 108 on 2013-02-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's been moved to github.  You can find the 1.6 branch at: https://github.com/ros-perception/image_pipeline/tree/image_pipeline-1.6 which is what was released into electric.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-02-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-02-03**:
The source link on the wiki is now correct, but the image_pipeline/Releases page is broken.